# I can't start an Activitiy by clicking a Button

Tags: java, android

i'm trying to start an Activitiy by clicking a Button. If the user clicks the PLAY button in the MenuActivity the GameActivity should be started. But it doesn't work.

```
public class MenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
}

public void startGameEngine(View view) {
    Intent myintent = new Intent(this, GameActivity.class);
    startActivity(myintent);
}
```

Here is the GameActivity class which should be started when the user click on the PLAY-Button.

```
public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
}
```

Here is the menu.xml file which includes the button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/menubackground_color"
    tools:context="com.example.vincenzoauricchio.example.MenuActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="381dp"
    android:layout_height="67dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="440dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/vt323"
    android:text="@string/logo2"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.666"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="265dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="87dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/vt323"
    android:onClick="startGameEngine"
    android:text="@string/button_play"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

Comment: what do you mean by *But it doesn't work* , try to mention the error/issue precisely, you may check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before posting

Comment: Have you added GameActivity in the Manifest?

Comment: Try my answer..

Comment: set `android:clickable="true"` in xml

Answer (score 1):

**Try this.**

```
public class MenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

    Button btnPlay= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
    btnPlay.setOnClickListener(this);

  }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId())
        {
            case R.id.btnPlay:
              Intent myintent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, GameActivity.class);
               startActivity(myintent);
            break;
        }
     }
}
```

Check your Activity in your **Manifestfile.xml** or not

Comment: remove this line     `android:onClick="startGameEngine"`..i hope this may help you

Answer (score 1):

**Try implementing the on click listner :**

```
public class MenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener
```

**Try below code snippet :**

```
Button btnPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
btnPlay.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);

 @Override
 public void onClick(View view)
  {
     if(view == btnPlay)
     {
           Intent intent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, GameActivity.class);
           startActivity(intent);
     }
  }
```

**Add your `GameActivity` to manifest.**

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity android:name=".GameActivity"/>
```

The clickOn on the **layouts.xml** are not always a good practice but they work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting your on click listener in the xml, set it programatically in the activities on create.

```
btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener{
     void onCLick(){
          startGameEngine();
     }});
```

and remove View view from `startGameEngine()`'s input value.

and make sure you add the GameActivity in the `manifest.xml`